# Cycle through popup list without arrow keys?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I am faily new to vim/nvim. To assist my learning I have disabled arrow keys:

```
nnoremap <right> <Nop>
nnoremap <left> <Nop>
nnoremap <down> <Nop>
nnoremap <up> <Nop>
```

When I access the `:` menu, start typing and press `<tab>`, I get a list of available options to select from. Usually, I would cycle through with the arrow keys. Obviously, that does not work anymore.

Is there another way to cycle though from the keyboard?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the cursor keys? Just use them if you think they are useful. You still have enough to learn. Anyhow, I guess you are looking for `<CTRL-N>` and `<CTRL-P>`.  Also have a look at `:h cmdline-completion`

Comment: Thanks. 

I don't think arrows are bad. I just want to get used to staying on the home row. Habit formation.

Comment: I'm curious Christian, why did you put this as a comment instead of an answer? (It worked btw!)